# Android Firebase separate data by device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android app connected to Firebase and I was wondering if it is possible to have the data saved separated by device, so that saving data on one device will not appear on another device with the same app. Is this possible without the implementation of authentication and different accounts?

Comment: Why not implement Firebase authentication?

Comment: @AlexMamo That would be my second plan, but I was wondering if it is possible to do it without just for ease sake. But how would I do it if I do use Auth? Is the data automatically separated between accounts if I add authentication or do I have to do something else?

Comment: Are you asking [how to get a unique device ID on Android?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+get+a+unique+device+ID+on+Android)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not sure but I will check that out! Is this a normal and good practice though? To access database based on device ID (assuming it's even possible)?

Comment: The device ID can change, the UID that comes from the authentication process will never change.